# Trying to Extract Content Between HTML Tags

Tags: html, regex, grep

I am trying to use grep to parse the file and print out text between HTML tags for an assignment using:

`grep -o '<font color="#FFCC00" SIZE=+1>' PROJECTS.HTML`

Is is not possible to use grep to extract between HTML tags? For example using: `grep -o '(<font color="#FFCC00" SIZE=+1>).*?(</font>)' PROJECTS.HTML`.

Here is sample of the HTML:

```
<li>                          
  <A HREF="./CS448/marbles_2020_1.tar" target="main">
  <font color="#FFCC00" SIZE=+1>
   Marbles - A marbles game (V2020) written on OPENGL for Linux. 
  </font>
  </A>
 </li>                          
 <li>                          
  <A HREF="./CS448/marbles_2020_2.tar" target="main">
  <font color="#FFCC00" SIZE=+1>
   Marbles - A marbles game (V2020) written on OPENGL for Linux. 
  </font>
  </A>
 </li>                          
</ul>
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser to parse HTML. Regular expressions are not a solution to everything.

Comment: Try `sed` or `awk` ( or whatever is used these days )...

Comment: the entire HTML file looks like the snippet above so there is no additional complexity to deal with there

Comment: Some of your HTML is at least 20 years [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features)

Comment: Sed was perfect for this use case, was able to extract the titles with a single sed command. Thanks, for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A million years ago, I would have used something like:

```
/<font color="#FFCC00" SIZE=+1>/,/<\/font>/p
```

as a script for `sed`...

(This goes back a long way... I may be wrong about bits of that.)

Seems both upper & lower case has been used for attributes. This could be a problem...

IF, as you wrote, this is all that is in the file, use inverse thinking and "grep out" the rows/tags you don't want. Something like:

```
grep -v "<li>" -v "</li>"...
```

Just an idea...

Comment: Sed was perfect for this use case, was able to extract the titles with a single sed command. Thanks, for the recommendation! –